# PHP function call fail

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wrote a part of code that doesn't execute and I can't find a way to fix it. It may be silly, but I'm a beginner in PHP world. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OAVi.png)

Comment: what  do you mean? do you get any error?

Comment: Please paste the code at the question, not an image. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your class instance incorrectly. This:

```
$ds=new AuthController();
```

Should be:

```
$ds=new AuthController;
```